# Implementing Multi-Zone / Multi-Region Cloud Function Failover in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm looking to find a solution to mitigate the impact of a regional / zonal outage for Cloud Functions like happened today (7.02.19).

My thought immediately went to a Load Balancer backend setup where there's a backend configuration that lets me hot-swap zones or regions.

My specific use-case doesn't really allow me to quickly swap out `http://us-east1-project-id.cloudfunctions.net/my-function` for `http://us-east4-project-id.cloudfunctions.net/my-function-2`

I feel like an LB in this situation is potentially a bad idea, but some place to point services at and then allows me to swap backends (manually or automatically) would be nice.

I've looked at a solution using NGINX to do this, though I feel like there's a way to do it.

Additionally, I've read a bit about Endpoints on GCP... though making this work isn't necessarily straight forward as it appears I also need to use some bits of Google App Engine.

Answer (score 1):

Given these functions encode region and project into the host name, I don't think DNS CNAMEs help here. You could run a proxy that rewrites requests to the appropriate region and function.

However, where are you going to host this that is as reliable and scalable as the functions service in a region? Given the goal of surviving regional outages, in theory you could run this in some other datacenter, but that costs a latency penalty.

> My specific use-case doesn't really allow me to quickly swap out
>   `http://us-east1-project-id.cloudfunctions.net/my-function` for
>   `http://us-east4-project-id.cloudfunctions.net/my-function-2`

Reconsider how the function URL is constructed. Making region project and function into variables makes a cut over procedure possible. I doubt writing a larger app to wrap the function is less work.